# Inputs no son "clickeables" en pantallas pequeñas

Tags: php, html

Pues eso, al visitar mi página desde un teléfono móvil me he fijado que en el formulario de registro no puedo clickar encima de los inputs, tan solo puedo hacer en los dos últimos.
la página de pruebas está [aquí](http://www.oneplayer.es/newop/register.php):
este es el código:

```html
   

<?php session_start();?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <?php 
  include ("template/head.php");
  include ("template/header.php"); 
  include ("db_files/db.php");
  ?>
   <body class="container-fluid no-padding">
  <button id="upbutton" class="hidden"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></button>
  <article>
     <section class="row no-padding no-margin">
        <div class="center-element col-md-10 col-xs-10">
           <center>
              <h2><?php echo $lang['register_string_1']; ?></h2>
           </center>
           <form action="regcheck.php" method="post" id="registerform">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                 <h3><?php echo $lang['register_string_2']; ?></h3>
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                       <label><?php echo $lang['register_string_3']; ?></label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="regname" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                       <label><?php echo $lang['register_string_4']; ?></label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="regsurname" required/>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <label><?php echo $lang['register_string_5']; ?></label>
                 <input type="email" class="form-control" name="regemail" required/>
                 <label><?php echo $lang['register_string_6']; ?></label>
                 <input type="number" class="form-control" name="regphone" required/>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                 <h3><?php echo $lang['register_string_7']; ?></h3>
                 <label><?php echo $lang['register_string_8']; ?></label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="regaddress"/>
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                       <label><?php echo $lang['register_string_9']; ?></label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="regcity"/>
                       <label><?php echo $lang['register_string_10']; ?></label>
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="regprovince"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                       <label><?php echo $lang['register_string_11']; ?></label>
                       <input type="number" class="form-control" name="regcp"/>
                       <label><?php echo $lang['register_string_12']; ?></label>
                       <select class="form-control" name="regcountry">
                       <?php
                          $strSQL = "SELECT id, nombre FROM paises";
                          $query = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
                          while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                           echo "<option value=".$result['id'].">".$result['nombre']."</option>";
                          } 
                          mysqli_close($db);
                          ?>
                       </select>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                 <label for="regpass"><?php echo $lang['register_string_13']; ?></label>
                 <input id="regpass" type="password" class="form-control" name="regpass" required/>
                 <label><?php echo $lang['register_string_14']; ?></label>
                 <input type="password" class="form-control" name="regrepass" required/>
                 <br><input type="checkbox" name="regterms" required/>  <?php echo $lang['register_string_16']; ?>
                 <input type="submit" class="my-btn btn-primary" value="<?php echo $lang['register_string_15']; ?>"/>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                 <br><br>
                 <center>
                    <p><?php echo $lang['register_string_17']; ?></p>
                 </center>
              </div>
           </form>
        </div>
     </section>
  </article>
   </body>
   <?php include('template/footer.php'); ?>
</html>
```

Comment: estás incluyendo 2 veces `bootstrap.min.css`, 2 veces `bootstrap.min.js`, 3 versiones diferentes de `jQuery`, el `jquery.form-validator.min.js` lo tienes antes de una libreria `jQuery`........

Comment: Entonces cuales son las correctas? porque yo he ido incluyendo líneas según lo que he ido encontrando para incluir esas librerias pero no sé cual es cual y ahora al quitar algunas de esas lineas me han dejado de funcionar ciertas cosas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fíjate que los primeros `div` tienen como clases `col-md-6 col-xs-12`, mientras que los dos últimos sólo tienen `col-md-6`. Las clases `col-xx-xx` añaden la propiedad `float:left` que harán que los elementos floten, pero en pantallas pequeñas no tienes definido el `col-xs-12` para los dos últimos `div`, estos no flotarán y se colocarán por encima de los dos primeros.

La solución es rápida y sencilla: le tienes que poner la clase `col-md-6 col-xs-12` a los dos últimos `div` y el problema se resolverá.